# php random function to call same random value

Tags: php, html, sql

I am making a online quiz which have id opt1-opt4 and answer in database.

I am calling the questions using function

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "ashu","ashua");
$db=mysql_select_db("quiz",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2");

if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {


echo "<form method=post action=".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].">";
echo "<table border=0>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

$id = $row["id"];
$question = $row["question"];
$opt1 = $row["opt1"];
$opt2 = $row["opt2"];
$opt3 = $row["opt3"];
$opt4 = $row["opt4"];
$answer = $row["answer"];

echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>Q:$question</b></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt1\">$opt1 </td></tr>";
echo"<tr><td> <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt2\">$opt2     </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt3\">$opt3 </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt4\">$opt4 </td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

}
```

and i want to call the righ answer using

```
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz ");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display))
{

$question = $row["question"];
$answer = $row["answer"];
 $q = $_POST["q$id"];

echo "<tr><td><br>$question</td></tr>";

if ($q == $answer) 
    {
    echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You answered $q, which is correct</td></tr>";
    }
elseif ($q == "") {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You didn't select an answer. The Correct answer is $answer</td>     </tr>";
}
else {
echo "<tr><td>&raquo;You answered $q. The Correct answer is $answer</td></tr>";
}

}
echo "</table></p>";



}
```

but it gives all the database value i want only those values which is randomly called for question
How it is possible to get same random values in `php` this display all the question from data base I want to display only those which are generated randomly.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in php random function anywhere in your code.

Comment: i tryed but not working

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php. Can you update your question to indicate what you have tried and what exactly is not working.

Comment: i want to display the answer of those question which are randomly generated but my script showing all the answer whic are stored in datbase not randomly generated question which are set to two.

Comment: means in database there is 3 questions and randomly i am genrating only two question but on submit it shows amswer of all the three questions

Comment: Then you might want to add a flag/column to the quiz table to indicate if this question was selected for random display. Then while showing the answer you can filter by that random flag/column to show answers only for those questions that were randomly generated.

Comment: yes but dont have idea that how it done

Comment: I gave you a general idea. You might want to proceed with it and then post here if you run into any issues. This is how this site works. You need to show what you have tried and what exactly is not working.

Comment: Another approach could be to add a hidden field for the question id on the first page and then on the 2nd page,  get the answer to the question based on the id from the hidden question id field.

Comment: there is an hidden id in the database